# Find the function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Find all functions $f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ such that they satisfy $|f(x)-f(y)|\ge |x-y|$ $\forall x,y\in[0,1]$

I Could only find that $\{f(0),f(1)\}=\{0,1\}$

Comment: What about $\,f(x)=x\,$ ...?

Comment: @Don:i said 'ALL'

Comment: I'm overwhelmed you did, @Neeraj: I only offered you one example, and that's why I did not write an answer.

Answer (score 5):

$f(x)=x$ works fine.  So does $f(x)=1-x$.  The trick is to show that they are the only ones.  First you must have $f(0)$ be either $0$ or $1$ and $f(1)$ be the other.  Lets start with $f(0)=0,f(1)=1$.  Now assume there is a $b$ such that $f(b) \neq b$.  Your requirement will fail at one end or the other, depending on whether $f(b) \gt b$ or $f(b) \lt b$.